# MySql Distinct with multiple fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql, distinct

I have 4 columns a, b c, d in my table (MySQL database) . I want to select the distinct values of ALL of these 4 columns in my table . More deeply my table is given bellow..

```
a   b   c   d
--------------------------
1   3   3   4
1   2   3   0
1   1   3   4
1   2   3   4
1   2   3   4
1   2   3   4
1   2   3   4
```

In the above table (1,2,3,4) value are repeating 4 times(look the last 4 rows of my table). I want only the distinct one , ie i want to get the bellow table after mysql query..

```
a   b   c   d
---------------
1   3   3   4
1   2   3   0
1   1   3   4
1   2   3   4
```

I think you guys got some idea . Im not familier with MySql .

Comment: Which one do you want? Note that in the absence of a PRIMARY KEY a 'table' is not really a table in an RDBMS sense.

Comment: have you tried distinct keyword before the column names?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
select distinct a,b,c,d from your_table
```

Comment: Its working well..I have 1 more need , ie there is 2 more fields in ma table(e & f). I want to get the corresponding values also.How can i do that??

Comment: jsut add select distinct a,b,c,d,e,f from your_table

Comment: I want to avoid that field from unique condition.If i add that filed also then , does the mysql check the unique condition for that field also??

Comment: Yes, it does. But if you don't want those other fields to be unique you have to define a rule which one to take because you can't take all, right? Would be best to ask another question and add your example data and expected output.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name,column_name FROM table_name;
```

I mean

```
select distinct a,b,c,d from table_name;
```

Here is the link of [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

Answer (score 0):

use :
`SELECT DISTINCT * FROM yourtable`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a FROM my_table
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT b FROM my_table
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT c FROM my_table
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT d FROM my_table
```

***update 1:***

```
SELECT a,b,c,d 
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY a,b,c,d;
```

***http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c49ad/11***

Comment: what would be the output of this query

Comment: what is the benefit of using Distinct keywords with Group By?

Comment: @Nimesh, if you wants to remove the duplicate means use the distinct or otherwise use the group by like its aggregate operators to each group

Comment: and have you checked your first query result in fiddle?

Comment: @Nimesh, yeah I'm asking try this and I'm not trying to say exact one... you should read all thinks..

Comment: @jmail OP has already suggested the output and your first query result does not match with the suggested output.

Comment: @Winky exactly what I am asking to jmail. OP has suggested 4 columns with distinct value but, the first query returns the single column only.